# Change text color for GtkToggleToolButton with CSS sheet (GTK+3)

Tags: css, c, button, colors, gtk

I'm trying to use a CSS sheet for changing properties on my GTK/C application. In a dialog, I have a GtkToolBar with GtkToggleToolButtons. I would like that texts of these buttons are of different color.

I used to write something like that in a CSS sheet:

```
#histoToolGreen {
  color: green;
}

#histoToolBlue {
  color: blue;
}
```

and it was working with GTK 3.20 (but only when buttons was off). But now, with gtk update, it is not working anymore.
The name of the buttons are histoToolGreen and histoToolBlue.

Could you tell me how to change color of GtkToggleToolButton using a CSS sheet ?

Comment: The current version is 3.20; are you running master? That being said, that's definitely weird; I'd have ot try it myself...

Comment: I use version in debian testing repositories: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gtk+3.0

Comment: And for clarification, how are you defining the button names? In code with `gtk_widget_set_name()`? In code with `g_object_set("name")`? In a .ui file? I ask because I can confirm this but others cannot...

Comment: This is in .glade file. I've set ID AND Widget name to histotoolBlue and Green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try changing the color of the label rather than that of the button. Buttons are really just clickable bins. Buttons with text are just a helpful constructor which automatically adds a label.

```
#histoToolGreen label {
  color: green;
}

#histoToolBlue label {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip, but you should edit your message.The right code is : #histoToolGreen label { color: green; }

Comment: Updated. I think the format I used is deprecated in newer version of GTK.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a last question. If I try to do it in C, it doesn't work. Any idea  : gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, "#histoToolRed label {color: red}" or even gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, "* {color: yellow}"?

Comment: I can't tell from what you've provided. If you flesh it out to a full separate question I'll take another look though.

Comment: Do you think that is relevant to ask another question ?

Comment: OK, I've posted my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250497/change-text-color-for-gtktoggletoolbutton-in-c-code-gtk3